# How to operate Android from PC

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, touchscreen, broken-screen

Is there any way to completely use my android phone from my PC ? I got a damaged display and touch will not work for some parts of my phone. the phone is Sony Xperia J. My phone currently have a default lock screen (sliding from left to right) as that part of touch is not working, I cannot access my phone. Please help. Android Version is 4.2.

Comment: You might wish to check our [broken-screen tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info), which has quite a few useful hints for that situation. A detail needed in this context: Is USB debugging enabled on the device?

Answer (score 1):

The following reply needs USB Debugging option to be activated on the target device.

You can easily operate your device with [Vysor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm), it's an Extension for Goolge Chrome.

- Refer to the link below for further details : [How to fully control your android device from any computer](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/fully-control-your-android-device-from-any-computer-0164097/)

Comment: actually, I can't unlock my phone...

Comment: without device permission u can't operate any application in android.i think you can change your  display first that in under 1k that is better way for this problem .. other wise try some flashing method that is not sure for your device

Answer (score -1):

You can install snapPEA on your PC, and also make sure USB Device drivers are working fine.

Using snapPea you can manage the apps, music, photos, and SMS messages on your Android phone from your PC. Its free for windows.